# To much padding/margin/whitespace in Summary view of Links List

Tags: list-view, links-list

I have a problem with the Summary view of a Links list. If one if the links is so long that it have to be displayed over two lines then all the links get the same height in the presentation. This leads to a lot of whitespace in the view.

Pictures:

[image: As displayed]
[image: With td padding and scribbles to explain better]

I've tried to find the cause of this by inspecting the CSS but i cant find a rule that explains this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the source and solution of the problem. The source is a `&nbsp;` in line 563 of `14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\LinksList\List\schema.xml`:

```
<td style="padding-bottom: 5px" class="ms-vb"><img src="/_layouts/images/square.gif" alt="" />&#160;</td>
```

I'm not sure what that `&nbsp:` is doing there but adding `nowrap="nowrap"` to the first td in the listing solved the vertical white space issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the XSLT file located

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\XSL\vwstyles.xsl

and edit line 1377 from

```
<td style="padding-bottom: 5px;" class="ms-vb">
```

to

```
<td style="padding-bottom: 5px; white-space: nowrap;" class="ms-vb">
```

Comment: I wouldn't change core files if I where you.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add to this old question as this issue still occurs in SharePoint 2013.

Adding the following jQuery to your masterpage will fix the issue globally:

```
    $('.ms-summarycustombody td.ms-vb:first').css('white-space', 'nowrap');
```

Thank you to the OP for figuring this out... the `&nbsp:` doesn't show up in firebug so this was doing my head in until I found this question.

Cheers